# Retrieving a fragment state

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onsaveinstancestate, android-savedstate

I have a form in my fragment and I want to restore the filled data if screen goes off or user presses the home button.

When the screen goes off, `onSaveInstanceState` and `onPause` methods are called and I can persist the state in one of these methods.

For example

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    for (CustomTextInputLayout inputField : formHelper.getCustomTextInputLayoutList()) {
        editor.putString(inputField.getId() + "", inputField.getText());
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

Or I can persist in `onSaveInstanceState` via `outState` bundle.

But when I try to retrieve saved state, I could not have found the proper method. I tried `onActivityCreated` and `onViewStateRestored` but none of these methods are called after screen goes off and then the fragment comes to foreground again.

What can be the best solution to this problem ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

When you're saving state with `onSaveInstanceState` into a `Bundle`.
You will receive this `Bundle` during recreation of a `Fragment`, so just check it in the `onCreate` method.

```
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

Comment: onCreate is not called after onPause or orSavedInstanceState.

Comment: Yes, it is not called right after onPause, but your fragment still holds its data until destroyed, you don't have to restore anything